# Trailing 6 months value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table which shows the 
Project,PCT ,Month .

We need to capture average value based on the trailing six months for PCT for each project.

Thanks

Comment: Start with reading https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter for the last 6 months with `where`, and `group by` project:

```
select  Project
,       avg(PCT)
from    YourTable
where   DateColumn > dateadd(month, -6, now())
group by
        Project
```

(The query assumes a column with type `datetime` and name `DateColumn`.)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have data for each month, you can use window functions:

```
select t.*,
       avg(pct) over (partition by project
                      order by month
                      rows between 5 preceding and current row
                     ) as avg_pct_6
from t;
```

This assumes that the average you want is six months including the current month.  If you are not including the current month, then:

```
                      rows between 6 preceding and 1 preceding
```